# attempt to access external Api with Authorization Encrypted gets 401 error typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, api, authorization

I need to access an external api, I was able to access it with its Authorization and get data but when I encrypt it with  btoa function I get error 401 can anyone help me what is the problem? Am I not encrypting well?
this code run well
[image]
but if I did:
[image]
I get 401 error:
[image]

Comment: When you made the original API call it was not encrypted, so why are you doing encryption of the token, does the server or API support token encryption?

Comment: This is an exercise that I was allowed to do, in the instructions of the exercise it was written that the * Authorization key (9874654654987654658) cannot be exposed on the client side.

Comment: there is any one know???